# Sensitivity Lagrangian solution general case

Tags: constrained-optimization, reference-request, numerics

I have asked this question already on [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913987/lagrange-multiplier-sensitivity-implicit-constraint) and [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310766/sensitivity-of-lagrangian-solution-implicit-constraint).

Just a question about a literature reference. I am writing a paper for engineers.

Usually for the Lagrange multiplier problem

$$
\nabla f(x)+\lambda \nabla g(x)=0
$$

the sensitivity result that the multiplier $\lambda$ gives the sensitivity for changes in the constraint function is derived for the case $g(x)−h=0$ for varying $h$.
Is there somewhere a reference deriving this for $g(x;h)=0$?

I looked through the literature and asked one expert. No trace of such a proof. But there must be one, I am sure.

I can do it myself, however, I would like to avoid to reinvent the wheel.

I am only looking for a hint for a reference, no explanations how to do it.

Comment: If I remember correctly then Nocedal and Wright's book Numerical Optimization contains a proof or a reference to the proof.

Comment: Only for the linear case unfortunately.